# Error con Tailwind css y html: No me permite centrar el texto

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid-layout, tailwind

tengo un error al centrar el footer...Así es como quiero que quede el footer:

Hello, I have an error when centering the footer...This is how I want the footer to look:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como queda:
This is how it looks:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" data-theme="cupcake" class="h-full">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CarpiShop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/output.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@500&family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="bg-indigo-900 grid grid-cols-2 min-h-full min-w-full">
    
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1 class="text-white font-body text-2xl p-5">Shop Story</h1>
        </header>
        <nav class="grid place-content-start m-10 p-10">
            <button class=" btn btn-primary m-2 p-2  text-white font-display   bg-indigo-900 border-0"><i class="bi bi-inbox m-1 p-1"></i>Todos los productos</button>
            <button class=" btn btn-primary m-2 p-2  text-white font-display  bg-indigo-900 border-0"><i class="bi bi-1-circle m-1 p-1"></i>Abrigos</button>
            <button class=" btn btn-primary m-2 p-2  text-white font-display  bg-indigo-900 border-0"><i class="bi bi-2-circle-fill m-1"></i>Camisetas</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary m-2 p-2  text-white font-display   bg-indigo-900 border-0"><i class="bi bi-3-circle m-1 p-1"></i>Pantalones</button>
            <button class=" btn btn-primary m-2 p-2  text-white font-display   bg-indigo-900 border-0  "><i class="bi bi-bag-fill m-1 p-1"></i>Carrito</button>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div>
        <main>
            <h1>Hola</h1>
        </main>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-2">
        <footer class="bg-black text-center justify-center justify-items-center justify-self-center content-center min-h-full min-w-full ">
            <h1 class="text-yellow-500   ">Pagina vanilla HTML + CSS + JS</h1>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

He usado css Grid para maquetar la página, pero ahora no sé cómo centrar la parte final de la página

I have used css Grid to layout the page, but now I don't know how to center the bottom part of the page

Comment: Hola! Has estado usando bootstrap o tailwind. El título de tu pregunta hace referencia a bootstrap, pero no tu código.

Answer (score 0):

podrias agregar la propiedad flex al footer y quedaria como quieres, le agregue flex al código y le removí varias propiedades, fijate

```html
<footer class="bg-black text-center justify-center items-center flex h-52">
    <h1 class="text-yellow-500">Pagina vanilla HTML + CSS + JS</h1>
</footer>
```

prueba eso y para cambiar el alto del footer modifica el h a los niveles que quiere